# Not found or missing file

Tags: c#, linux, windows-10, monodevelop

I am working on a cross platform Gui app using c# Visual Studio on Windows. I was hoping to port my code to linux via Monodevelop because i have tried it with another project and it worked.
However in this particular project I happen to use EasyTabs dll to create a chrome tabs on my app. The projects is error free on windows but on linux i get a dll exception error and one dll it says is missing is that of **uxtheme.dll**

I have tried to copy the uxtheme dll from my windows *C:\Windows\System32*
To my project and add it to my .csproj and even copied it to my debug and release folder. However this has not been successful. Any workable idea would do.

Comment: looks like this wont work on linux coz of the missing dlls

Comment: But am not giving up on trying to go cross platform

Comment: You shouldn't expect any Windows specific things to work in the cross platform manner. More can be found in https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you are trying to run a winapi project on linux. While Monodevelop may look like it support windows envirnonment on linux os it is very important to note that not all dll and supportive windows runtime files are available. You have to look for missing dll files to fix your problem or simply write a program that does not require them at all

Comment: I agree with you that monodevelop can enterly support everything or anything on windows